# Android code help for removing from end of the list

Tags: java, android, arrays, api, sorting

My API is supposed to get me a list of clothes/mobiles/etc.

But, there are few extra elements in each of the list.

For Example:

- Coats
- Jackets
- Trousers
- Jeans
- ...
- Suits
- clothes_types
- testing_1

Sample Code:

```
private ItemArrayAdapter adapter;

public void onCreate(...)
{
...
adapter = new ItemArrayAdapter(...);
...
adapter.addAllItems(itemList);
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

I don't have access to fix the APIs or Backend Database.

I need to remove the extra elements from the end of the list.

Please help in deleting the extra elements with a generalized code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**itemList** = the list of items for a particular category

**n** = number of items to delete in that list

> Create a method like below:

```
private void deleteExtraElementsFromEnd(int n, ArrayList<item> itemList)
{
    for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
        itemList.remove(itemList.size()-i);
}
```

> Call this method whenever you need to delete elements from the list, like:

```
{
...
adapter = new ItemArrayAdapter(...);
...
deleteExtraElementsFromEnd(2, itemList)
adapter.addAllItems(itemList);
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Hope it helps.

[Reference for More Info](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/ArrayList)

Comment: oh... thnx 
got it